# Runge-Kutta (RK4) derivative in C++

Tags: c++, derivative, runge-kutta

Hello I created a small simulation of movement in C++. There are material points that move and bounce when hit the spheres I wanted to demonstrate to students differences beetwen Euler, Runge-Kutta and MidPoint methods.

But I did a mistake somewhere when I switch to the Rungy-Kutta mode all the material points dissapear. The mistake I've made is in the solveRK4 method.  MinGW Developer Studio project in the attachment, also there are libraries folders to put into mingw compiler directory.:
http://speedy.sh/CvDHj/LABO3.zip

When you press 'R' button it switches to RK4 when 'E' to Euler when 'M' to MidPoint.

**The question is where did I make a mistake in solveRK4 function?**

The result(release) looks like that: http://speedy.sh/h28VP/zad3.exe press R and the points will go out off the screen.

Punkt - Point
Wektor - Vector

The main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <GL\glut.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "struktury.h"

#define YS 1.0f
#define PI 3.1415


double rot=0.0f;
int solver=0;

//--------------------------------------------------------------
//
//  to solve
//  {dr/dt=v
//  {d2r/dt2=F/m
//
//  Solvery:
//      solveEuler
//      solveMidpoint
//      solveRK4
//
//  
//--------------------------------------------------------------

void derivatives(Wektor *in, Wektor *out, Punkt *p){
    // dr/dt =v
    // d2r/dt2=F/m
    out[0]=in[1];
    out[1]=p->f*(1.0/p->m);
}


void calcForce(Punkt *p, Wektor v){
//  p->f = p->m * 9.72 -  (1 * v) ;
}

void solveEuler(Punkt  *p,  float dt){
    Wektor in[2] , out [2];
    in[0] = p->r ;
    in[1] = p->v ;
    derivatives(in, out ,p);
    p->v = p->v + out [1] * dt;
    p->r = p->r + out [0] * dt;
}

void solveMidPoint(Punkt *p, float dt){
    //r,v,f ->Wektor
    Wektor k1[2],k2[2];
    Wektor y_k[2];
    Wektor y_h[2];
    Wektor yout[2];

    y_h[0]=p->r;
    y_h[1]=p->v;
    derivatives(y_h,yout,p);

    k1[1]=yout[1];
    k1[0]=yout[0];
    y_k[0]=y_h[0]+k1[0]*0.5*dt;
    y_k[1]=y_h[1]+k1[1]*0.5*dt;
    derivatives(y_k,yout,p);
    k2[1]=yout[1];
    k2[0]=yout[0];
    p->r=p->r+k2[0]*dt;
    p->v=p->v+k2[1]*dt; 


        }
    //MISTAKE HERE  mistake here
    void solveRK4(Punkt *p, float dt){
    //r,v,f ->Wektor
    Wektor k1[2],k2[2],k3[2],k4[2];
    Wektor y_k[2];
    Wektor y_h[2];
    Wektor y_a[2];
    Wektor y_b[2];
    Wektor yout[2];

    y_h[0]=p->r;
    y_h[1]=p->v;
    derivatives(y_h,yout,p);
    k1[0]=yout[0];
    k1[1]=yout[1];
    y_k[0]=y_h[0]+k1[0]*0.5*dt;
    y_k[1]=y_h[1]+k1[1]*0.5*dt;
    derivatives(y_k,yout,p);
    k2[1]=yout[1];
    k2[0]=yout[0];
    y_a[0]=y_k[0]+k2[0]*0.5*dt;
    y_a[1]=y_k[1]+k2[1]*0.5*dt;
    derivatives(y_a,yout,p);
    k3[0]=yout[0];
    k3[1]=yout[1];  
    y_b[0]=y_a[0]+k3[0]*dt;
    y_b[1]=y_a[1]+k3[1]*dt;
    derivatives(y_b,yout,p);
    p->r=p->r+y_b[0]+yout[0]*dt;
    p->v=p->v+y_b[1]+yout[1]*dt;    
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------
// RESZTA KODU
//--------------------------------------------------------------




struct SferaN{
       Wektor r1;
       float r;
       float t;
       float color[3];
       SferaN *right;
};



Wektor g(0,-1.0,0);
 Punkt *root=NULL;
 SferaN *sroot=NULL;
 int loop=0;
SferaN *SphereAlloc(float R, Wektor r1, float t, float c[3])
{
       SferaN *tmp;
       if (!(tmp=(SferaN*)malloc(sizeof(SferaN))))
          return NULL;

        tmp->right=NULL;
        tmp->r=R;
        tmp->r1=r1;
        tmp->t=t;
    tmp->color[0]=c[0];
    tmp->color[1]=c[1];
    tmp->color[2]=c[2];

        return tmp;
}

void SphereTest(SferaN *s, Punkt *p)
{
 float d;
 Wektor n;
 float z;
 d=(s->r1-p->r).len();
 if (d-s->r<0)
 {
    n=(s->r1-p->r);
    n.norm();
    z=d-s->r;
    p->r=p->r+n*z;

    Wektor vs,vn;
    vn=n*(n*p->v);
    vs=p->v-vn;
    p->v=(vs-vn*s->t);
 }


}

void AddSphere(SferaN *ro, float R, Wektor r1, float t, float c[3])
{
     SferaN *tmp;
     for (tmp=ro; tmp->right!=NULL; tmp=tmp->right);

        tmp->right=SphereAlloc(R,r1,t,c);
}


Punkt *PointAlloc(float m, int flaga, Wektor r, Wektor v)
{
      Punkt *tmp;
      if (!(tmp=(Punkt*)malloc(sizeof(Punkt))))
         return NULL;

      tmp->m=m;
      tmp->flag=flaga;
      tmp->r=r;
      tmp->v=v;
      tmp->right=NULL;
      return tmp;
}

void AddPoint(Punkt *ro, float m, int flag, Wektor r, Wektor v)
{
     Punkt *tmp;
     for (tmp=ro; tmp->right!=NULL; tmp=tmp->right);

        tmp->right=PointAlloc(m,flag,r,v);
}

Wektor W_Euler(Wektor f, float h)
{
       return (f*h);
}

void calcDeriv(Punkt *p){

}

void Solver(Punkt *ro, float dt)
{
    //0 euler, 1 midpoint, 2 RK4
     Punkt *tmp;
     for (tmp=ro;tmp!=NULL;tmp=tmp->right)
     {
         switch (solver){
         case 0:
             solveEuler(tmp,dt);
             break;
         case 1:
             solveMidPoint(tmp,dt);
             break;
         case 2:
             solveRK4(tmp,dt);
             break;
        default:
            solveEuler(tmp,dt);
         }
    /*
     tmp->dv=W_Euler(tmp->f*(1/tmp->m),dt);
     tmp->v=tmp->v+tmp->dv;

     tmp->dr=tmp->v*dt;
     tmp->r=tmp->r+tmp->dr;
    */

        /*
    Wektor a=tmp->f*(1.0/tmp->m);        
         //--------------

    Wektor k1=W_Euler(a,dt);
    Wektor k2=W_Euler(a+0.5*k1,dt);
    Wektor k3=W_Euler(a+0.5*k2,dt);
    Wektor k4=W_Euler(a+k3,dt);
    Wektor kk=(1.0/6.0)*(k1+2.0*k2+2.0*k3+k4);
    tmp->v=tmp->v+kk;
    tmp->r=tmp->r+tmp->v*dt;
    */

     }
}

void Sily(Punkt *ro)
{
     Punkt *tmp;

     for (tmp=ro;tmp!=NULL; tmp=tmp->right)
     {
        tmp->f=g*tmp->m;
     }
}




void AnimateScene(void)
{
         glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);

     //if (loop==0)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        Punkt *tmp;
        //Sily(root);
        Solver(root,0.008); 
        Sily(root);
    //  glRotatef(0.1,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);

rot+=0.01;
//if (rot>36) rot=0.0f;
        glPointSize(5);
  glDisable(GL_LIGHTING); 
  glDisable(GL_LIGHT0); 
        for(tmp=root;tmp!=NULL;tmp=tmp->right)
        {
        //glBegin(GL_POINTS);

               //glColor3f(rand()/(float)RAND_MAX,rand()/(float)RAND_MAX,rand()/(float)RAND_MAX);
               glColor3f(1,1,1);
              // glVertex3f(tmp->r.x/1.0,tmp->r.y/1.0,tmp->r.z/1.0);

            glPushMatrix();
            glTranslatef(tmp->r.x/1.0,tmp->r.y/1.0,tmp->r.z/1.0);
            glutSolidSphere(0.011,5,5);
            glPopMatrix();
               SferaN *stmp;

               for(stmp=sroot;stmp!=NULL;stmp=stmp->right)
               {

                  SphereTest(stmp,tmp);
               }
               //glVertex2f(0,0);
               //printf("%f %f\n",tmp->r.x, tmp->r.y);
       // glEnd();

        glBegin(GL_LINES);

                glColor3f(1,0,0);
                double x1,x2,y1,y2,z1,z2;
                x1=tmp->r.x;
                y1=tmp->r.y;
                x2=tmp->v.x;
                y2=tmp->v.y;
        z1=tmp->r.z;
        z2=tmp->v.z;


                glVertex3f(x1,y1,z1);
                glVertex3f(x1+(x2)*0.05,y1+(y2)*0.05,z1+(z2)*0.05);
        glEnd();

        }
  glEnable(GL_LIGHTING); 
  glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);         
        SferaN *stmp;
        for(stmp=sroot;stmp!=NULL;stmp=stmp->right)
        {
         glPushMatrix();
         glTranslatef(stmp->r1.x,stmp->r1.y,stmp->r1.z);
    glColor3fv(stmp->color);

         glutSolidSphere(stmp->r,50,50);
         glPopMatrix();
        }


      //  printf("****\n");

        glFlush();
        glutSwapBuffers();
        loop++;


        if (loop>2000)
        {
           double vx,vy,vz;
 double zz=0.01;

           for(tmp=root;tmp!=NULL;tmp=tmp->right)
           {
        vx=0.5-rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
        vy=1.0-rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
        vz=0.5-rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
        vz=0.0f;
        vy*=YS;
            vy+=zz;
            zz+=0.001;
            tmp->r.x=0;
            tmp->r.y=0;
            tmp->v=Wektor(vx,vy,vz);
           }
            loop=0;
        }
}

void InitGraphics()
{
  GLfloat mat_specular[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 }; 
  GLfloat mat_shininess[] = { 90.0 }; 
  GLfloat light_position[] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0}; 

  glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, mat_specular); 
  glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, mat_shininess); 
  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position); 
  glEnable(GL_LIGHTING); 
  glEnable(GL_LIGHT0); 
  glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL); 
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); 


        glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);




    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);


}


void myReshape(GLsizei w, GLsizei h) 
{ 
  glViewport(0, 0, w, h); 
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); 
  glLoadIdentity(); 

    double p1=1.0f;

  if(w <= h) 
     glOrtho(-p1,p1,-p1*(GLfloat)h/(GLfloat)w,p1*(GLfloat)h/(GLfloat)w,-10.0,10.0); 
  else 
     glOrtho(-p1*(GLfloat)w/(GLfloat)h,p1*(GLfloat)w/(GLfloat)h,-p1,p1,-10.0,10.0); 

  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 
  glLoadIdentity(); 
} 
void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y){
    switch (key){
    case 'e':
        solver=0;
        printf("Solver --> Euler\n");
        break;
    case 'm':
        solver=1;
        printf("Solver --> MidPoint\n");
        break;
    case 'r':
        solver=2;
        printf("Solver --> RK4\n");
        break;

    }
}
void idle(void)
{
        glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 double vx,vy,vz;
 int i;
 srand(time(NULL));

 double zz=0.01;

 for (i=1; i<620; i++)
 {
        vx=0.5-rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
        vy=1.0-rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
        vz=0.5-rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
    vz=0.0f;

        vy*=YS;
        vy+=zz;
        zz+=0.001;

    if (!root)
       root=PointAlloc(1,0,Wektor(0,0,0),Wektor(vx,vy,vz));
    else
        AddPoint(root,1,0,Wektor(0,0,0),Wektor(vx,vy,vz));
 }
 zz=-0.2;

 for (i=1; i<140; i++)
 {

       AddPoint(root,10,0,Wektor(zz,1,0),Wektor(0,0,0));
       zz+=0.01;
 }

    float c1[] = {0,0,1};
    float c2[] = {0,1,0};
    float c3[] = {1,1,0};
    float c4[] = {1,0,1};
    float c5[] = {0.6,0.5,1};
    float c6[] = {0.6,0.5,0.3};

  sroot=SphereAlloc(0.5,Wektor(0,-0.5,0),0.9,c1);
  AddSphere(sroot,0.1,Wektor(-0.5,0.5,0),0.8,c2);
  AddSphere(sroot,0.1,Wektor(0.5,0.5,0),0.3,c3);
  AddSphere(sroot,0.1,Wektor(1,0.0),0.3,c4);
  AddSphere(sroot,0.15,Wektor(0,0.7,0),0.9,c5);
  AddSphere(sroot,0.2,Wektor(-1,-0.2,0),1.0,c6);

        Sily(root);

        glutInit(&argc, argv);
        glutInitWindowSize(600,600);
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
        glutCreateWindow("GLUT example");



        InitGraphics();

        glutDisplayFunc(AnimateScene);
        glutIdleFunc(idle);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutReshapeFunc(myReshape); 
        glutMainLoop();

return 0;
}
```

STRUCTURES:

```
#ifndef __STRUKTURY_H
#define __STRUKTURY_H



class Wektor{
public:
       Wektor(double _x=0, double _y=0, double _z=0):
       x(_x),y(_y),z(_z){}

       Wektor operator+(Wektor const &);
       Wektor operator-(Wektor const &);
       double operator*(Wektor const &);
       Wektor operator*(double);

       double len();
       void norm();
       double x,y,z;
};

Wektor operator*(double, Wektor const &);


Wektor Wektor::operator-(Wektor const &w)
{
       return Wektor(x-w.x,y-w.y,z-w.z);
}

double Wektor::operator*(Wektor const &w)
{
       return (x*w.x + y*w.y + z*w.z);
}

double Wektor::len()
{
       return sqrt((*this)*(*this));
}

Wektor Wektor::operator+(Wektor const &w)
{
       return Wektor(x+w.x,y+w.y,z+w.z);
}

Wektor Wektor::operator*(double l)
{
       return Wektor(x*l, y*l, z*l);
}


Wektor operator*(double s, Wektor const &w)
{
       return Wektor(s*w.x, s*w.y, s*w.z);
}
void Wektor::norm()
{
     double d = len();
     if (d)
        (*this)=(*this)*(1/d);
}

struct Punkt{
        int flag;
        float m;

        Wektor f;
        Wektor r;
        Wektor v;

        Wektor dr;
        Wektor dv;

        Punkt *right;
};

#endif
```

Comment: And your question is? What have you tried to answer it?

Comment: i <3 simulations, and i wished to research that question as well! in the sense "what is the difference and is it worth calculation?" thanks4the sources! will compile and study it!!! +1 where are the fixes?) ok i will not be so lazy and will inspect your code as well! спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the indices in these lines seem wrong:

```
y_b[1]=y_a[0]+k3[0]*dt;

p->v=p->v+y_b[0]+yout[1]*dt;
```

Please read through your RK4 very carefully and inspect all the indices. There might even  be more copy/paste errors.

Comment: You are right. I have edited those two and do not see any other. When I press 'R' the accelerate and go out off screen, but I do not see any error. You can see the result -> exe file http://speedy.sh/h28VP/zad3.exe

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it, Works just fine now! :-)

**0.**
before you start - read [WIKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods#The_Runge.E2.80.93Kutta_method) paragraph, very carefully!

**1.** You did mistake in actual integration part, you wrote

```
 p->r = p->r + y_b[0] + yout[0] * dt;
```

which has nothing to do with wikipedia version of classic 4-th order runge-kutta mtehod. and here is a corect line:

```
 p->r = p->r + (yout[0][0] + 2* yout[1][0] + 2* yout[2][0] + yout[3][0] )*  dt * (1.0/6);
```

So, just take a look at wiki once more and compare.

**2.** Later on i had found a series of lines

```
y_a[...] = y_k[...] + k2[...] * 0.5*dt;

y_b[...] = y_a[...] + k3[...] * dt;
```

You should write:

```
y_a[0] = y_h[0] + k2[0] * 0.5*dt;
y_b[0] = y_h[0] + k2[0] * 0.5*dt;
```

using INPUT but not newly calculated proxy (temporary) values.
you messed with just that y_h, y_k, y_a y_b... y_qwertyuiop!!!!
dont name it like that)))

**3.** Also you got way too many variables... i made it more easy and readible, also uses less memory.

Anyways, less word more deal: here is the working method code, copy-paste and enjoy:

```
void solveRK4(Punkt *p, float dt) {
    Wektor y_in[2];
    Wektor y_temp[2];
    Wektor k[4][2];    
    y_in[0] = p->r;
    y_in[1] = p->v;
    derivatives(y_in, k[0], p);
    y_temp[0] = y_in[0] + k[0][0] * 0.5*dt;
    y_temp[1] = y_in[1] + k[0][1] * 0.5*dt;
    derivatives(y_temp, k[1], p);
    y_temp[0] = y_in[0] + k[1][0] * 0.5*dt;
    y_temp[1] = y_in[1] + k[1][1] * 0.5*dt;
    derivatives(y_temp, k[2], p);
    y_temp[0] = y_in[0] + k[2][0] * dt;
    y_temp[1] = y_in[1] + k[2][1] * dt;
    derivatives(y_temp, k[3], p);
    p->r = p->r + (k[0][0] + 2* k[1][0] + 2* k[2][0] + k[3][0] )*  dt * (1.0/6);
    p->v = p->v + (k[0][1] + 2 * k[1][1] + 2 * k[2][1] + k[3][1]) * dt * (1.0/6);
}
```

**4.** Do not use GLUT; use GLFW! ;-)